# signrank test in a three-dimensional array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, statistics

I have a 60x60x35 array and would like to calculate the Wilcoxon signed rank test to calculate if the median for each element value across the third array dimension (i.e. with 35 values) is different from zero. Thus, I would like my results in two 60x60 arrays - with values of 0 and 1 depending on the test statistic, and in a separate array with corresponding p values.

The problem I am facing is specifying the command in a way that desired output would have appropriate dimensions and would be calculated across the appropriate dimension of the array.

Thanks for your help and all the best!

Comment: I am not that fit in statistics, do you know and if so can you pls elaborate on how to compute the p-values?

Comment: [p,h] = signrank(M) - this returns the p value of the signed rank test for matrix M. h is a logical value (0 or 1), where h=1 indicates a rejection of null hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way to solve your problem is using a nested for-loop. Lets say your data is stored in `data`:

```
data=rand(60,60,35);
size_data=size(data);
p=zeros(size_data(1),size_data(2));
p(:,:)=NaN;
h=zeros(size_data(1),size_data(2));
h(:,:)=NaN;
for k=1:size_data(1)
    for l=1:size_data(2)
       tmp_data=data(k,l,:);
       tmp_data=reshape(tmp_data,1,numel(tmp_data));
       [p(k,l), h(k,l)]=signrank(tmp_data);
    end
end
```

What I am doing is I preallocate the memory of p,h as a 60x60 matrix. Then I set them to NaN, so if you can easily see if sth went wrong (0 would be an acceptable result). Now I loop over all elements and store the actual data array in a new variable. `signrank` needs the data to be an array so I reshape it to two dimensions. 
 
I guess you could skip those loops by using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @The Minion! This was really helpful and exactly what I required.